# Can I get single property values from Spring Cloud Config Server?

Tags: spring-cloud-config

I would like to get **single property values** from Spring Cloud Config Server with a **wget/curl call from the command line**.

Single values because otherwise I have to parse them out of the response and I want to **keep the bash-scripts as simple as possible**.

The documentation of Spring Cloud Config Server states the possibilities of the REST API as follows

```
/{application}/{profile}[/{label}]
/{application}-{profile}.yml
/{label}/{application}-{profile}.yml
/{application}-{profile}.properties
/{label}/{application}-{profile}.properties
```

Is there any **trick to get a single value**? I searched quite a bit but found nothing. Not a huge need as it seems.

Or can I **extend the EnvironmentController** of the Config Server to implement this feature? I didn't found any resources about extending the REST API of the Config Server.

Thanks for your help

Comment: why not grep for the property that you need?

Comment: to keep the scripts as simple as possible. Instead of greping for values in many scripts, it would be nice to solve the problem once on the Config Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question: Spring Config Server has some kind of **template mechanism**. With this you can **basically serve whatever you want**.

In the documentation this is not very obvious because it is called `Serving Plain Text`:
http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.3.4.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_serving_plain_text

Even the example in the documentation is not serving plain text, but a structured configuration format.

Comment: an example to along with this would go a LONG way...  after reading this, I still don't know how to pull a specific property out of CC

Comment: @jason It is a bit cryptic but it is a easy as doing a request to: `/app/profile/label/filename` 

Complete example: `curl localhost:8888/foo/default/master/nginx.conf`

Answer (score 4):

just to give an example to @burki's answer, you can put a file named `foo-details.json` and the contents can look like this:

```
{
    "my-custom-key": "${some.value.from.another.upstream.config:default-value}"
}
```

and when you GET that file from the config server, it will have replace values:

`https://config.your-company.com/foo-app/some-profile/some-branch-name/foo-details.json`